# My set function doesn't actually set a variable

Tags: php

So I'm busy on this new site, and since it includes a login system, and my designer doesn't know any PHP at all, I decided to make a quick system for him to use.

When he needs to echo user data, he takes the attribute and puts it between percentage signs (For example `%username%`. Then my class filters the document for those tags, and replaces them with the value I give them. So it works like this in the PHP class:

```
public static function setUser($key, $value)
{
    self::$user['%' . $key . '%'] = $value;
}
```

As you can see, I call this function with a key and a value, and it gets saved in an array, then, I call the `parseParams` function, which searches the page for these tags. The function:

```
private static function parseParams($content)
{
    $userkeys = array_keys(self::$user);
    $uservalues = array_values(self::$user);
    self::$output = str_replace($userkeys, $uservalues, $content);
    return self::$output;
}
```

The output is a page, since I call the `render` function. It does a `ob_get_contents` on the page I call, which then becomes the $content variable that gets parsed. When I echo the `$output` variable, I get the whole page.

Seems pretty simple. Now, my problem is that there aren't any variables set. An example of when I call the function, is when a user logs in. Here's the login function:

```
public function Login()
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $query = DB::$conn->prepare('SELECT username, password, rank FROM users WHERE username = ?');
        $query->bind_param('s', $username);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($name, $pass, $rank);
        $query->store_result();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            while ($query->fetch())
            {
                if (password_verify($password, $pass))
                {
                    TPL::setUser('username', $username);
                    session_start();
                    define('LOGGEDIN', true);
                    header('Location: me');
                    exit();
                }
                    else
                {
                    $this->loginMessage[] = '{{wrongpass}}';
                }
            }
        }
            else
        {
            $this->loginMessage[] = '{{nouser}}';
        }
    }
```

I did define the `TPL` class at the top of the file, under the namespace for the class:

`use CRF\Template as TPL;`

So, I was thinking this was a good solution, and it would work, but as soon as I do `var_dump(TPL::$user);` I get an empty array.

Where does my mistake lay?

Thanks.

Comment: _Where_ do you put that `var_dump(TPL::$user);`?

Comment: @Laxus I've put it in the index file, where everything comes together

Comment: You know that php is stateless, right? That `TPL::setUser('username', $username);`  that you have in Login() function will never parse by parseParams().

Comment: @Laxus I believe it does, since the 'setUsers' functions only sets it, and I call the Var in my template

Comment: But you don't call the var in that request. You make a redirect to `me` and then you exit. In your `me` page `Template::$user` is empty.

Comment: Use the `$_SESSION` variable for persisting data in sessions. That's what it's made for.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley Will do, much easier solution. Thanks anyway guys!@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TPL::setUser('username', $username);
session_start();
$_SESSION['tpl_user']=serialize(self::$user);
define('LOGGEDIN', true);//btw this also won't be saved for the next script
header('Location: me');
exit();
```

you can not pass variables from one page to another that way. But you can store them in your $_SESSION var, something like this in file with logging in:

```
TPL::setUser('username', $username);
session_start();
$_SESSION['tpl_user']=serialize(self::$user);
define('LOGGEDIN', true);//btw this also won't be saved for the next script
header('Location: me');
exit();
```

and this in your file that uses that array:

```
private static function parseParams($content)
{
  if(isset($_SESSION['tpl_user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['tpl_user'])) //session_start() should be called before that code
   {
    self::$user = unserialize($_SESSION['tpl_user']);
    $userkeys = array_keys(self::$user);
    $uservalues = array_values(self::$user);
    self::$output = str_replace($userkeys, $uservalues, $content);
    return self::$output;
   } else {println("Access fobidden"); exit;}
}
```